# jquery v1.3.2 find element by attribute or cssclassname

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

hi I am using a list view for showing selection marks.

```
 <asp:listview id="lvanswerlist" runat="server">
 <layouttemplate>
  </layouttemplate>
<itemtemplate>
 <asp:Panel ID="Idanswercontent" CssClass="answer" runat="server">
              <div class="bestAnswerControl">
                   <div id="divBestAnswer" class="bestAnswer" runat="server">
                     <%-- best answer control goes here --%>
                   </div>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID = "hfObjectID" runat="server" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID = "hfIsBestanswer" runat="server" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID = "hfQuestionId" runat = "server" />
              </div> 
<asp:/panel>
</itemtemplate>
 <asp:/listview>
```

i am adding css class

```
.bestAnswer
{
background-image:url('contrl/Vote/Images/before_accept2.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
cursor:pointer;
height:35px;
width: 35px;
margin-left: 24px;   
}

/*.bestAnswer:hover
{
  background-position: 0 100%;
}*/
.IsBestanswer
{
background-image:url('control/Vote/Images/after_accept.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
cursor:pointer;
height: 38px;
width: 38px;
margin-left: 24px; 
}
```

I want to add functionality like if I select another answer as a best answer then previous selected best answer image shuld be change.

How can I do this with jQuery?

I am thinking like

Comment: Wow can you at least put *some* effort into question formatting? I think you owe that to the folks that solve your problems.

Comment: @Tomalak, agreed and done. @Nishant, could you complete the final sentence to clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: I hate people who don't complete a

Comment: actually i want to change css class for bestanser when another answer is selected. like if there is five answer in list, intially 3rd answer is selected now user select 4th answer then i want to mark 3rd answer as unselcted like remaing answer except4th answer. actually i am using here two class 1st for best answer and 2nd for  isbestanswer after selcteing a best answer i want to apply  isbestanswer class and remove previous  selected answer isbestanswer class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)?... these functions have been around since jQuery 1.0.

```
$('.bestAnswer').click(function(){
 $('.IsBestanswer').removeClass('IsBestanswer');
 $(this).addClass('IsBestanswer');
})
```